# Database transaction log content

Tags: database

Hi pretty basic question here.

As far as I understand the log records transactions and some data related to them. Are the original values stored or just the operations performed?

Comment: It will depend on your database system (SQL Server; MySQL; Oracle), and the logging options set (for SQL Server: Bulk, Full, or Simple).  I'm curious why you want to know..

Comment: You want to read the documentation for a particular implementation. The oracle docs are pretty detailed but if you have an interest in the underlying code look at open source mysql/postgres and see how it is implemented.

Comment: @Stuart, it is a question from a database design test